# Detect Internet Connectivity

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am trying to figure out a way to do an internet connectivity check for an AIR for iOS app. Previously, I was using (against my better judgement) a `URLMonitor` that checked Google once every 30 seconds. I did not like putting that load onto Google and neither did they; this morning, our network got flagged as a possible DDoS attacker simply from testing the app. So I had to disable this type of check and move on.

I have thought about using the [`NetworkInfo` ANE](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air/extensions/networkinfo.html) from Adobe, but that presents its own issues in determining internet connectivity. The only way I can think of doing it is to check for interfaces "en0" and "pdpxx" (which correspond to WiFi and Cellular interfaces, respectively) and check their IPs to ensure they are not in the 192.168.x.x, 10.10.x.x, or 127.0.x.x ranges. However, I am not entirely sure those are the only static router/localhost IPs out there and there is always the possibility that the network interface names will change in the future, which would render this monitor useless. There is also the issue of IPv6 possibly throwing a wrench into this method as well.

Is there another way to check if the user is connected to the internet? I've searched multiple times and it seems that these are the only two ways to check. If that is the case, what is the best way to check?

Comment: A simple approach would be to poll the actual server. When a poll request fails, set a flag to indicate the user is offline. When off line you use cached data **and** poll the server at a lower frequency (ie: every 30 seconds). When the polling request succeeds, you can resume polling at the faster frequency and use the live data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that you got flagged as a DDoS attacker, are you sure that's what happened?

In any case, if your not happy with putting the load onto someone else's server, then make your own server, just a basic setup that you use with the URLMonitor. You don't have to use google's url with the URLMonitor, you can pass it another URLRequest, which could point to your own server.

```
monitor = new URLMonitor(new URLRequest("http://www.you-own-server.com"));
```

This might also be useful if you decide that you want to pass more data between the app and the server. It's your server, so can do what you want with it.

I don't think there's any other way to check if the user is connected to the internet. To be honest, I don't see why there would be. Checking for the users interfaces/wan0 etc... probably would be possible, but you'd need another program, maybe a simple python or c++ program, that Air could use to check these things, but that sounds like the long way round.

Comment: It's not an option. The client is expecting 80k active users of the app. They do not have the infrastructure to handle such a load. We are using their servers for various data polling, but we need to know before we do a poll if we should used cached data or poll the server and they cannot handle so many page hits every 30 seconds.

Comment: And yes, I could use interfaces (via an Adobe-built Native Extension). But as I described in my question, there are flexibility issues with that. That may be the best option, however. And I did some digging into our routers and confirmed that the only major Google pings were coming from my test devices, so it definitely got us flagged.

Comment: I see. Well I don't think the client can expect to have 80k+ users without having some sort of infrastructure behind it. Unfortunately that puts you in an awkward position as the developer. Did your network get suspended or anything? It might have been some automatic response from the ISP or something? Remember that just about everyone that has used the URLMonitor is using google as the test. It can certainly handle another 80k users pinging its servers, so I would just bite the bullet and use googles servers if the client is unwilling to implement their own server.

Comment: It was definitely a Google response. See this [Google Support question](http://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en) regarding it. And they have the infrastructure to handle the data requests, but their IT department has told me they cannot be sure they will be able to support so many hits every 30 seconds and has forbid me from doing it. Unfortunately, that is out of my hands and is not an option. EDIT: See [this page](http://sorry.google.com/sorry/?continue=http://www.google.com.) to see what Google gave me.

Comment: Well you could write your own URLMonitor, which checks the headers from the a URLLoader (looking for response code 200) and it only checks every 2 minutes or so. That should stop your DDos problems with google. I can't really see any other way around this. Your going to need to ping a server somewhere, might as well make it googles, since they can certainly handle it.

Comment: The problem is that 2 minutes is not often enough. Hell, the 30 seconds I ended up using wasn't often enough to catch everything. Using Google is out of the question after getting this error from them. EDIT: It's also worth noting that according to various unsourced answers on SO, it also breaks Google's TOS (unsurprisingly).

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like a bit of a problem then. I'm sorry I couldn't be more help to you. I hate when developers are put in positions like this. I developed an 'always online' app around a year ago, and used Amazons EC2 servers to handle checks (handling around 65k users). The whole thing was scaleable, so when there was high loads, more servers would start up... and low loads they would shut down accordingly. This worked incredibly well and was surprisingly cheap. I can only wish you the best of luck with this, I'm all out of ideas.